# How to add an alias to a value inside a pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble creating an Alias within a Pivot based on the values as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT trntypeid, trnstatusid, errorcodeid
    FROM trndatacore 
    WHERE companyid = 374 
        AND trntypeid = 7 
        AND trndatetime BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-03-01' 
        AND trnstatusid IN (11,13)
) AS Sourcetable
PIVOT (
    COUNT(errorcodeid)
    FOR errorcodeid IN ([300] as Invalid BSB, [301] as GeneralDecline)
) AS ClientReport
```

When I run this query I receive a syntax error for the alias within the FOR statement of the pivot. I've tried adding quotes to the alias names, square brakcets however I don't believe this to be the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well you can't have a space in alias name so I expect that is your issue.

Comment: Same way you add an alias to any other column - in the column list of the select statement, `SELECT [300] as [Invalid BSB], ...`

Comment: use [Invalid BSB] instead

Comment: Why make an alias with a space?  Alias is only used internally to the query -- no one but you will see it.  There is no advantage to putting a space in except you have to add in the quotes when you use it.  (Which is not an advantage its a PITA)

Comment: I tried removing the space for the alias in addition to adding square brackets to the alias name however this returned the same syntax error.

Comment: AFAIK, can't alias in the IN clause. I tried.  And you can't SELECT 300 and 301 because they aren't fields until the PIVOT executes. Build your PIVOT query then build another query that pulls from the PIVOT query and use alias there.

Comment: I'm trying to add a column name for each errorcodeid and I think I've mistakenly thought the alias would archieve this. How would you suggest doing that Hogan?

Comment: How many errorcodeid's are there? Perhaps you need a table that maps errorcodeid to a name and use that in your pivot. I use Access CROSSTAB and appreciate that IN clause is not required.

Comment: There are 6 errorcodeid's that I need to label in my pivot. Would you do this mapping within the query itself?

Comment: No, I don't see any way to do that. Include table with CodeName field and use that field.

Comment: As I said, couldn't alias within PIVOT but in another query referencing PIVOT query. Answer posted by Patrick shows this.

Comment: Alias the pivot with cross apply..`SELECT alias.*
FROM (SELECT trntypeid, trnstatusid, errorcodeid...PIVOT (
    COUNT(errorcodeid)
    FOR errorcodeid IN ([300], [301])
) AS ClientReport
cross apply (select ClientReport.*) as alias(trntypeid, trnstatusid, InvalidBSB, GeneralDecline)`

Answer (score 1):

It's really helpful to provide example DML and DDL when you ask a question.
From your question I mocked some up for you:

```
DECLARE @trndatacore  TABLE (CompanyID INT, trntypeid INT, trndatetime DATETIME, trnstatusid TINYINT, errorcodeid INT)
INSERT INTO @trndatacore (CompanyID, trntypeid, trndatetime, trnstatusid, errorcodeid) VALUES
(374, 7, '2023-01-01', 11, 300), (374, 7, '2023-01-01', 13, 301), (374, 7, '2023-01-01', 13, 300), (374, 7, '2023-01-01', 11, 301);
```

Using that data, here's an example of how to apply an alias to a pivoted column:

```
SELECT trntypeid, trnstatusid, [300] AS InvalidBSB, [301] AS GeneralDecline
FROM (
    SELECT trntypeid, trnstatusid, errorcodeid
    FROM @trndatacore 
    WHERE companyid = 374 
        AND trntypeid = 7 
        AND trndatetime BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-03-01' 
        AND trnstatusid IN (11,13)
) AS Sourcetable
PIVOT (
    COUNT(errorcodeid)
    FOR errorcodeid IN ([300], [301])
) AS ClientReport
```

| trntypeid | trnstatusid | InvalidBSB | GeneralDecline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 11 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 13 | 1 | 1 |

The trick to it is doing it in the outer part of the select, when the pivoted columns are available by their values. In this case those values are illegal (you can't start with a number) so they must also be escaped.